# AJAX Toolkit ConfirmButtonExtender not opening Confirm Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, confirmbuttonextender

I cannot get the Confirm to fire on the button click. There is the Registration at the top of the ASP page:

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
```

Here is the code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetSelectedReports" runat="server" 
    Text="Download Selected Report(s)" 
    OnClick="btnGetSelectedReports_Click" BackColor="#337AB7" 
    ForeColor="White" Width="500px" Height="36px" Font-Bold="True" 
    Font-Size="Medium" />      
<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btnGetSelectedReports_ConfirmButtonExtender" 
    runat="server" 
    BehaviorID="btnGetSelectedReports_ConfirmButtonExtender" 
    ConfirmText="The selected report(s) will be written to your folder. Do you wish to continue?" 
    TargetControlID="btnGetSelectedReports" 
    OnClientCancel="btnClearAll_Click()">
</asp:ConfirmButtonExtender>
```

In the web.config file:

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolKit"/>
</controls>
```

And of course where I've added the script manager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fyi, there's an extra `>` after the ScriptManager closing tag. What happens if you remove `BehaviorID`?

Comment: @wazz fixed the extra > thanks, removed the BehaviorID but got the same result.

Comment: I'm assuming by not working, you mean that it posts back anyway?  Or is the button click being prevented?

Comment: @Brian Mains I'm not seeing the Confirm window, so everything is proceeding as if there was no Confirm window there, post back occurs, Select query runs and redirect happens. It does show a white border around the btnGetSelectedReports button after the click.

Comment: On the button, try using UseSubmitBehavior="False", and see if that changes anything.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior?view=netframework-4.8